# Does Sql JOIN order affect performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was just tidying up some sql when I came across this query:

```sql
SELECT 
        jm.IMEI ,
        jm.MaxSpeedKM ,
        jm.MaxAccel ,
        jm.MaxDeccel ,
        jm.JourneyMaxLeft ,
        jm.JourneyMaxRight ,
        jm.DistanceKM ,
        jm.IdleTimeSeconds ,
        jm.WebUserJourneyId ,
        jm.lifetime_odo_metres ,
        jm.[Descriptor]
FROM    dbo.Reporting_WebUsers AS wu WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Reporting_JourneyMaster90 AS jm WITH (NOLOCK) ON wu.WebUsersId = jm.WebUsersId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Reporting_Journeys AS j WITH (NOLOCK) ON jm.WebUserJourneyId = j.WebUserJourneyId
WHERE   ( wu.isActive = 1 )
        AND ( j.JourneyDuration > 2 )
        AND ( j.JourneyDuration < 1000 )
        AND ( j.JourneyDistance > 0 )
```

My question is does it make any performance difference the order of the joins as for the above query I would have done

```
FROM dbo.Reporting_JourneyMaster90 AS jm
```

and then joined the other 2 tables to that one

Comment: Try running both and viewing the execution plans. Are they any different? I wouldn't expect them to be.

Comment: I've never heard of it affecting performance.

Comment: If such a simple query is slow, I would assume you need to look at the indexing.

Comment: It wasn't slow - it just seemed weird that you would select all the columns from one table but not have it as the main FROM table, but then that got me to thinking about performance as this needs to be scalable as it will be handling a lot of data

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 - Order of Inner Joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334944/sql-server-2005-order-of-inner-joins)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, the JOIN by order is changed during optimization.

The only caveat is the Option [FORCE ORDER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) which will force joins to happen in the exact order you have them specified.

Comment: I just had an example using MySQL where it did matter, because I was ordering on a Date which was joined in from another table. Switching the order decreased the execution time by 20%. And then, adding paging, it reduced execution time by 80%. So I guess it depends.

Comment: In a query I'm currently working on in SQL Server, changing JOIN order does change the plan and it make a significant difference. Kitster answer explains the reason though.

Answer (score 64):

Join order in SQL2008R2 server does unquestionably affect query performance, particularly in queries where there are a large number of table joins with where clauses applied against multiple tables.

Although the join order is changed in optimisation, the optimiser does't try all possible join orders. It stops when it finds what it considers a workable solution as the very act of optimisation uses precious resources.

We have seen queries that were performing like dogs (1min + execution time) come down to sub second performance just by changing the order of the join expressions. Please note however that these are queries with 12 to 20 joins and where clauses on several of the tables.

The trick is to set your order to help the query optimiser figure out what makes sense. You can use Force Order but that can be too rigid. Try to make sure that your join order starts with the tables where the will reduce data most through where clauses.

Comment: I have been working with SQL server for over 10 years and for the first time started seeing JOIN order affect performance like is stated in this answer. Baffled, having thought the optimizer knows best, I stumbled upon this while searching for others who had seen the same behavior. Yes, my statistics are all up to date.

Comment: This may just be a parameter sniffing issue too, where any change to the query at all would have improved things.

Comment: @TomTom Even Grant Fritchey's Cost-based optimizer book talks about this specific scenarios where the "optimizer gives up" on complex queries. He is even able to demonstrate it using demo DB from Microsoft.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  FWIW: My complex, large Oracle query had never finished till I changed the order of joins.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a ton of joins. I am experiencing a significant difference (~200ms vs ~7500ms) on a query with just 4 tables. One join clause uses an IN expression, but otherwise a pretty small query.

Answer (score 11):

I have a clear example of inner join affecting performance. It is a simple join between two tables. One had 50+ million records, the other has 2,000. If I select from the smaller table and join the larger it takes 5+ minutes.

If I select from the larger table and join the smaller it takes 2 min 30 seconds.

This is with SQL Server 2012.

To me this is counter intuitive since I am using the largest dataset for the initial query.

Comment: It would enhance your answer if you could show the execution plans for both scenarios

Comment: Well, maybe the where clause limits the large table into a tiny set while it cannot reduce your smaller table?

Answer (score 7):

Usually not. I'm not 100% this applies verbatim to Sql-Server, but in Postgres the query planner reserves the right to reorder the inner joins as it sees fit. The exception is when you reach a threshold beyond which it's too expensive to investigate changing their order.

Answer (score 6):

`JOIN` order doesn't matter, the query engine will reorganize their order based on statistics for indexes and other stuff.

For test do the following:

- select show actual execution plan and run first query
- change `JOIN` order and now run the query again
- compare execution plans

They should be identical as the query engine will reorganize them according to other factors.

As commented on other asnwer, you could use `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to use exactly the order you want but maybe it would not be the most efficient one.

AS a general rule of thumb, JOIN order should be with table of least records on top, and most records last, as some DBMS engines the order can make a difference, as well as if the FORCE ORDER command was used to help limit the results.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. I just made exactly what you suggested and query runtime dropped 25%. In addition, to be sure it's not a fluke, I made changes using same logic to another CTE in my query and it INCREASED runtime by 60%.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the JOIN order does change the plan for a query I'm working with. So I think what you mean is JOIN order *shouldn't* matter, but sometimes it does.

Answer (score -5):

Wrong. SQL Server 2005 it definitely matters since you are limiting the dataset from the beginning of the FROM clause.  If you start with 2000 records instead of 2 million it makes your query faster.