# Is the chaining order of filter(...) and exclude(...) crucial?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.6

Is there no difference between the following examples?

Query 1:

```
objects.filter(a=b).exclude(c=d).filter(e=f).exclude(g=h).distinct()
```

Query 2:

```
objects.filter(a=b).filter(e=f).exclude(c=d).exclude(g=h).distinct()
```

Comment: No. You can verify that by doing `objects.filter(a=b).exclude(c=d).filter(e=f).exclude(g=h).distinct().query` and `objects.filter(a=b).filter(e=f).exclude(c=d).exclude(g=h).distinct().query` - The order of joins would be different, but the results would be the same.

Comment: That is right, but does the order of joins matter?

Comment: Well.. Order of joins would not matter for the result.

Comment: ... but probably for performance.

Comment: [Join order doesn't matter for performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360860/does-sql-join-order-affect-performance)