# SQL Join ON field differences

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding the use of JOINS from SQL:

What's the difference between:

```
Select * From Employees E
JOIN Products P ON E.idEmployee = P.idEmployee
JOIN ProductsDetails PD ON P.idProduct = PD.idProduct
```

AND

```
Select * From Employees E
JOIN Products P ON P.idEmployee = E.idEmployee
   JOIN ProductsDetails PD ON PD.idProduct = P.idProduct
```

Also, what's the difference between:

```
Select * From Employees E
JOIN Products P ON E.idemployee =P.idemployee
Where P.name like '%prod01%'
```

AND

```
 Select * From Employees E
    JOIN Products P ON E.idemployee =P.idemployee
    Where E.ProdName like '%prod01%' //considering the fact that the field ProdName also exists in the table Products.
```

Actually, how does a query actually works, I mean the workflow:

```
Select * From Employees E
JOIN Products P ON E.idemployee = P.idEmployee
JOIN ProductsDetails PD ON P.idProduct = PD.idProduct
JOIN OtherTable OT ON E.idField = OT.idField
where E.ProductNumber = 1 and OT.idOfAnotherField = value
```

How does the where condition on the Join clauses affects the main query, how does the query actually works , what it brings first and how does it applies the conditions?

Comment: Alls those questions are already answered on stackoverflow. Please search first. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360860/does-sql-join-order-affect-performance In general, it depends on the rdbms that you're using(f.e. MS SQL-Server or Oracle). The order can be changed by the optimizer.

Comment: I wonder what `ProdName` is doing in `Employees` table.

Comment: It was just an example based on the real queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  That is, a `select` statement describes the results produced by processing the data, but not the methods used to achieve it.  Two important parts of the database engine are the *optimizer* which determines how the query will be executed and the *execution engine* which actually executes it.

From the perspective of the optimizer, `col1 = col2` and `col2 = col1` are the same.  So, there is no difference in the first two queries.  From the perspective of what the query does, the two examples with `name` are the same.  Or, at least, superficially the same.  The two product columns could have different collations set, which would affect the meaning.

As for your final question, you need to look at your database documentation.  Specifics on the execution are highly database dependent.  You should also learn about `explain` and execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Difference between the first two queries, you just providing the criteria of joining the two tables, so Table1.FieldName = Table2.FieldName is the same of Table2.FieldName = Table1.FieldName.

The Difference between the second two queries is in the first one you searching for product name in the product table, and the second in the Employee table.

If there a product With name like '%prod01%' in the product table then the first query will return it and the second will not, and if there a product with name like '%prod01%' in the employee table the second query will return value and the first will not.

The query start by building the join, starting by select the Employee table then join the values of Employee table and Product table where the idemployee equal idEmployee and do the same with Products and ProductsDetails table and ProductsDetails table and OtherTable at the end the query filter the result based on the ProductNumber of Employee Table and idOfAnotherFields of OtherTable.