# Does my previous SQL query/ies affect my current query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have multiple SQL queries that I run one after the other to get a set of data. In each query, there are a bunch of tables joined that are exactly the same with the other queries. For example:

Query1

```
SELECT * FROM
Product1TableA A1
INNER JOIN Product1TableB B on A1.BId = B.Id
INNER JOIN CommonTable1 C on C.Id = B.CId
INNER JOIN CommonTable2 D on D.Id = B.DId
...
```

Query2

```
SELECT * FROM Product2TableA A2
INNER JOIN Product2TableB B on A2.BId = B.Id
INNER JOIN CommonTable1 C on C.Id = B.CId
INNER JOIN CommonTable2 D on D.Id = B.DId
...
```

I am playing around re-ordering the joins (around 2 dozen tables joined per query) and I read here that they should not really affect query execution unless SQL "gives up" during optimization because of how big the query is...

What I am wondering is if bunching up common table joins at the start of all my queries actually helps...

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Unless you're updating the table structure or modifying data in the table then 1 query shouldn't "affect" a subsequent query against that table.

Comment: Also, SQL Server's version is relevant as older versions seem to be more sensible to JOIN ordering than the newer ones. Please, edit your question and add the appropriate tag. (sql-server-xxxx).

Comment: If you are in MySQL, occasionally the results of the first query are cached and re-used if you run a query that resolves to the same run plan as the previous query.  Unsure if SQL-Server does that.

Comment: @Twelfth >>>the results of the first query are cached and re-used<<< Unsure that MySQL or any other RDBMS "cached and reuse the **RESULTS**". What is chached instead is the DATA. Of course if you read the same tables in different queries within small time interval, subsequent executions will not read data from disk but from cache(buffer pool)

Comment: @sepupic - I would have thought that too. 
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html   "The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again. The query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another client."  It was phased out after 5.7 apparently.

Comment: @sepupic - It was horribly dangerous to us...I would run my query in 12 seconds, and the developer next to me would run the same thing in 50ms just after despite it having the same runplan.   I don't consider MySQL a RDBMS anymore than I consider a Gremlin a car mind you.

Comment: The first thing that I see going to your link was this one "Note.
The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0."

Comment: Hehe, I saw it too...it's why I added that part to the bottom of my comment.  I was in mysql 5.5 when I went through that particular hell.

Comment: I can even tell you WHY this was not implemented in SQL Server. At work we have around 50 databases on our prod server and 4 of them are of 3Tb. What the hell will we cache the RESULTS when our PLE is less than 100? Our buffer pool is not enough even to permit our DWH elaboration without reading every time from disk

Comment: Maybe MySQL was thought to elaborate data of 100Mb, not 100Tb, so they could permit to cache the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what he was trying to say/to do:

> What I am wondering is if bunching up common table joins at the start
>   of all my queries actually helps...

Imagine that you have some queries and every query has more than 3 inner joins. The queries are different but always have (for example) 3 tables in common that are joined on the same fields. Now the question is:
what will happen if every query will start with these 3 tables in join, and all the other tables are joined after?

The answer is it will change nothing, i.e. optimizer will rearrange the tables in the way it thinks will bring to optimal execution.

The thing may change if, for example, you save the result of these 3 joins into a temporary table and then use this saved result to join with other tables. But this depends on the filters that your queries use. If you have appropriate indexes and your query filters are selective enough(so that your query returns very few rows) there is no need to cache intermediate no-filtered result that has too many rows because optimizer can choose to first filter every table and only then to join them

Comment: "The answer is it will change nothing" <-- thanks! So there's no more reason to "improve" on the current queries further. I was already able to clean it up and I was wondering if there was even more room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the order of the `join`s in the `from` clause doesn't make a difference on query performance.  For a small number of tables, there should be no difference.  The optimizer should find the best execution path.

For a larger number of tables, the optimizer may have to short-circuit its search regarding `join` order.  It would then be using heuristics -- and these could be affected by `join` order.

Earlier queries would have no effect on a particular execution plan.

If you are having problems with performance, I am guessing that `join` order is not the root cause.  The most common problem that I have in SQL Server are inappropriate nested-loop joins -- and these can be handled with an optimizer hint.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess when joining 2 dozen tables then it does matter how I order my joins although "earlier queries would have no effect on a particular execution plan".

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is a good explanation, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020843/2780791) explains the JOIN's behavior and also specifies that SQL Server's version is relevant:

> Although the join order is changed in optimisation, the optimiser
>   does't try all possible join orders. It stops when it finds what it
>   considers a workable solution as the very act of optimisation uses
>   precious resources.

While the optimizer tries its best in choosing a good order for the JOINs, having many JOINs creates a bigger chance of obtaining a not so good plan.

Personally, I have seen many JOINs in some views within an ERP and they usually ran ok. However, from time to time (based on client's data volume, instance configuration etc.), some selects from these views took much more than expected.

If this data reaches an actual application (.NET, JAVA etc.), a way is to cache information from all small tables, store it as dictionaries (hashes) and perform O(1) lookups based on the keys.

This provides the advantages of reducing the JOIN count and not performing reads from the database for these tables (except once when caching data). However, this increases the complexity of the application (cache management).

Another solution is use temporary tables and populate them in multiple queries to avoid many JOINs per single query. This solution usually performs better and also increases debuggability (if the query does not provide the correct data or no data at all, which of the 10-15 JOINs is the problem?).

So, my answer to your question is: you might get some benefit from reordering the JOIN clauses, but I recommend avoiding lots of JOINs in the first place.